# javascript: compare two strings, skip character which is different

Tags: javascript

right now this stops when it reaches a character that is different between the two strings. is there a way to make it skip a character that doesn't compare?

```
var match = function (str1, str2) {
    str1 = str1.toString(); str2 = str2.toString();
    for (var i = 0; i < str1.length; i++) {
        for (var j = str1.length - i; j-1; j--) {

            document.body.innerHTML += str1.substr(i, j);

            if (str2.indexOf(str1.substr(i, j))!==  -1) {
                return str1.substr(i, j);
            }
        }
    }
    return '';
}
document.body.innerHTML += (match("/some[1]/where[1]/over[3]/here[1]", "/some[1]/where[1]/over[4]/here[1]"));
```

http://jsfiddle.net/92taU/3/

expected: `/some[1]/where[1]/over[]/here[1]`

Comment: Don't use `return` if you want to stay in the function.

Comment: Collect the results instead of returning early.

Answer (score 1):

this does what are you looking for:

```
var match = function (str1, str2) {
    str1 = str1.toString(); str2 = str2.toString();
    ret=''; i=0; j=0; l=str1.length; k=0; m=0;

    while(i<l && j<l)
    {
        // If char is equal just add!
        if(str1[i]==str2[j])
        {
            ret+=str1[i];
            i++;
            j++;
        } else {
            // If it's different search next equal char...
            for(k=i;k<l;k++)
            {
                for(m=j;m<l;m++)
                {
                    if(str1[k]==str2[m])
                    {
                        // if char is found adjust indexes and break current for
                        i=k;
                        j=m;
                        k=l; // to break m for
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return ret;
}
document.body.innerHTML += (match("/some[1]/where[1]/over[3]/here[1]", "/some[1]/where[1]/over[4]/here[1]"));
```

It returns:

```
/some[1]/where[1]/over[]/here[1]
```

Different lengths are allowed.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming the two strings you're comparing will always be the same length. Here's some code that should do what I think you're asking for:

```
var match = function (str1, str2) {
    var i = 0;
    while (i < str1.length) {
        if (str1.substr(i, 1) !== str2.substr(i, 1)) {
            break;
        }
        i++;
    }
    if (i === str1.length) {
        return str1;
    } else {
        return str1.substr(0, i) + match(str1.substr(i + 1), str2.substr(i + 1));
    }
}
document.body.innerHTML += (match("/some[1]/where[1]/over[3]/here[1]", "/some[1]/where[1]/over[4]/here[1]"));
```

Starting at the beginning of each string, this code finds the longest substring. When a mismatch is found, it grabs that matching substring, skips the next character and repeats the process using a recursive function call on the remaining characters from each string.